# For Loop to get tables from multiple urls and bind stops at last url

Tags: r

I am using the below code to access multiple urls (in this case just two) and obtain specific tables from within. I then want to join them together in a df. However my loop only returns the last two tables (from the first url). But I need the tables from the second also.

```
# declare variables
team = 'ARI'
year = '2023'
day = '010'
months = c(10,11)
             
#initialize the empty list    
final = list()
    
      for (i in months) {
                   
            url <- paste0('https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/',team, '/', team, year, month, day, '.shtml')
              
            game_path <- url |>
                               read_html() |>
                               html_nodes(xpath = '//div[contains(@id, "batting")]') |> 
                               map(\(x) x |> 
                                     as.character() |> 
                                     str_remove_all("<!--|-->") |> 
                                     read_html() |> 
                                     html_table()) |> 
                               unlist(recursive = FALSE)
            
            
            final[[i]] <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, game_path)     
        
        }
```

I am guessing that the `final[[i]] <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, game_path)` line is not working. As I understood, you can initialize an empty list, then the `final[[i]]` would store the data, and I could then bind. But that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: It does not look like the URL is changing within the loop. The variable month is not defined in your code snippet.

Comment: You need to change `month` to `i` in your `paste0()` function